# qml XmlListModel plugin not found

Tags: xml, qml

In my project I'm trying to use the Xml List Module built in to qml but when I compile to a phone I get this error

```
W/Qt      (20100): assets:/qml/FlickrDemo/main.qml:4 ((null)): assets:/qml/FlickrDemo/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" plugin "qmlxmllistmodelplugin" not found
```

any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE

with both of the sudgested imports I just get this output on both my samsung galaxy note 2 and vivo

```
E/        ( 8142): Device driver API match
E/        ( 8142): Device driver API version: 23
E/        ( 8142): User space API version: 23 
E/        ( 8142): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Nov 29 14:18:37 KST 2013 
D/OpenGLRenderer( 8142): Enabling debug mode 0
W/Qt      ( 8142): assets:/qml/Demo2/main.qml:4 ((null)): assets:/qml/Demo2/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" plugin "qmlxmllistmodelplugin" not found
```

UPDATE 2

.pro file

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/Demo2
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

QT += qml quick network positioning

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Installation path
# target.path =

QT += xmlpatterns xml

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Rectangle {
    id:screen
    height: 1280; width: 720

    XmlListModel{
        id:listmodel
        source:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dogs"
        query:"/feed/entry"
        namespaceDeclarations: "declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';"
        XmlRole{name:"img_title"; query: "title/string()"}
        XmlRole{name:"img_source";query:"link[@rel=\"alternate\"]/@href/string()"}
    }

    transitions:[
        Transition{
            NumberAnimation{
                target:layout
                property:"x"
                easing: Easing.OutSine
                duration:250
            }

        }
    ]
    states: [
        State {
            name: "view"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: layout
                x:-screen.width
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: btn_back
                opacity:1
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: te_search
                opacity:0
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: btn_search
                opacity:0
            }
        }
    ]

    Row{
        id:layout
        height:screen.height - te_search.height

        ListView {
            id: listview
            width:screen.width
            height:screen.height - te_search.height
            clip:true

            model: listmodel

            delegate: Item {
                width:parent.width
                height:80
                Image {
                    id:thumbnail
                    width:parent.height
                    height:parent.height
                    anchors.left:parent.left
                    //source:img_source
                    source:"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrUkD2AQtkUmcazQ0P9JCxJBn-_lMHiRI2XdiB5s17ho6dv3UP"
                    onSourceChanged: print("Your image source is : " + img_source)
                }
                Text{
                    id:txt_title
                    anchors.left:thumbnail.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    anchors.right: txt_arrow.right
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                    elide:Text.ElideMiddle
                    text:img_title
                }
                Text{
                    id:txt_arrow
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.rightMargin: 10
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    font.pixelSize: 25
                    text:">>"
                }
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:{
                        console.log("clicked")
                        screen.state = "view"
                        console.log(img_source + " " + img_title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Image{
            id:big_pic
            width:screen.width
            height: screen.width - te_search.height - 10
            fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "http://www.hq.xinhuanet.com/photo/2013-02/04/114603916_21n.jpg"
            //source: img_source
        }
    }

    CTextInput{
        id:te_search
        y: 321
        height: 31
        anchors.right: btn_search.left
        anchors.left: screen.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.bottom: screen.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        Behavior on opacity {NumberAnimation{}}
        text:"Search Pics"
    }

    Button {
        id: btn_search
        height: te_search.height
        x: 276
        y: 326
        text: qsTr("Search")
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        Behavior on opacity {NumberAnimation{}}
        anchors.right: screen.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 5
    }

    Button {
        id: btn_back
        height: te_search.height
        x: 276
        y: 326
        opacity: 0
        text: qsTr("<< Back")
        Behavior on opacity {NumberAnimation{}}
        anchors.left: screen.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        onClicked: screen.state = ""
    }

    Text{
        x: 0
        y: 0
        anchors.top: screen.top
        text:"Tester"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 70
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**

try to add **XML support** to your **.pro** file

```
 QT + = xmlpatterns xml
```

[UPDATE 2]
try also

```
Projects --->Android kit armeabi-v7 ---> run ---> Deploy configurations 

--->additional libraries --->add  

---> browse toQTpath/.../android_armv7/qml/QtQuick/XmlListModel
```

and choose **libqmlxmllistmodelplugin.so**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sorry that didn't work either

Comment: ill try it, but just one question. Do you think you could  help me by looking at my other question as i haven't had any luck with any help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037612/online-qml-json-parser-error-qtquick

Comment: in regards to this thread please see my updated question. Thank you

Comment: can you give a minimal example that reproduces this error ,thanks

Comment: I had a look in my installation folder and this is what I saw http://paisei.com/stack/screen_1.png and http://paisei.com/stack/screen_2.png, There was 2 folders QtQuick and QtQuick.2 and in the second one there was nothing in there. would that have any reason to why I would be having all these problems?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you help me fix this then you have helped me soooooo much. thanks

Comment: Check the **UPDATE 2** sorry dude , I misunderstood you.I think you are deploying to an android phone.I tried and it didnt work for me.Later I added manually the library as shown above and worked perfectly on Android 4.1 .Good luck and you are welcome anytime :)

Comment: I really hate to be a pain in the ass lol. I was deploying to an android device and I also tried you solution above and now instead of a blank white screen with the error above, my app now crashes with a fatal error on my phone

Comment: I tried it on android armv_5 and your solution worked like a charm. thank you so much. If I might ask what is the difference between armv5 - 7? and did you see my other question that I posted about JSonListModel in the comments above? If so what do you think of that?

Comment: For **ARM** eabi-v7 or v5 ,these are different processor architectures and you can get more general info at wikipedia  if you want.I'll have a look at your other Q and dont forget to mark the answer if it helped .Regards :-)

Comment: Very very helpful, your a top member. Thanks again

Comment: For new visitors: You only need `QT + = xmlpatterns xml` then clean + qmake + build