# My Qt-QML application works OK on Fedora but stops working on android.It uses XmlListModel

Tags: android, qt, qml

I'm developing an **Android** application using **Qt and Qt Quick technology**. Every thing is OK on my Fedora box. 
In QML part of my app I use a `XmlListModel` and when I run it On Android, debugger says :

```
module "QtQuick.XmlListModel" plugin "qmlxmllistmodelplugin" not found
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082556/848068) but now my program on Android stops working at the beginning.
Even after above solution the debugger's output is :

```
W/System.err( 5815): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libQt5XmlPatterns.so" needed by "libqmlxmllistmodelplugin.so"; caused by library "libQt5XmlPatterns.so" not found
```

I'm using **Qt 5.3.2**, on **Fedora 20** and my NDK version is **r9c**.

Comment: Do you add xml module in your project file `QT += xml` ?

Comment: @jbh yeah. `QT+= xml xmlpatterns`

Comment: It could be a problem related to the APK creation. Qt Creator was not able to include `Qt5XmlPatterns` and `Qt5Xml`, the missing libraries which are probably causing the error. Which Android kit are you using?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I solved my problem by including QtXmlPatterns library manually yesterday. you are right.

Comment: @saeed Well done. :)